# How big a problem is 'Cannot find map file.' boot message?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, logs, sysvinit

This is a follow-on to another question that I have asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401414/linux-kernel-cannot-find-map-file).

To summarise: I am trying to boot a linux kernel that I have configured and built myself, as part of a Linux From Scratch (LFS) installation. However, I am seeing the following line in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Oct 9 17:24:17 <lee_lfs> kernel: Cannot find map file.
```

I've been reading through the source code for klogd (this is using SysVinit) and the problem seems to be that the map file doesn't contain the 'version' line that klogd is looking for.

Anyway, my question is: how big of a problem is this? What sorts of problems might this potentially cause? Is it something I can just ignore and the system should still boot up and run ok, or is this a problem that needs to be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer to my own question: I can confirm that the custom kernel that I've built does boot and and seem to run fine, even if the map file is completely removed. So, it doesn't appear to be a critical requirement, from the point-of-view of booting up the system. However, as Matt O. said in his answer, it seems that it may make debugging harder, if the memory locations can't be matched-up to the symbols that the System.map file contains.

Answer (score 1):

> How big of a problem is this.

Fairly significant. IE: your distro may be unusable.

> What sorts of problems might this potentially cause?

That's a bit difficult to tell but if you watch your kernel log you should be able to tell fairly quickly.

> Is it something I can just ignore and the system should still boot up and run ok, or is this a problem that needs to be solved?

I don't think it's a problem you can ignore if you value stability. I say this in the way that's harder to debug your system without it.

Well, I can see a couple things happening.

The kernel is either not building system.map, the symlink is not created, or some permissions are causing the problem.

If it helps system.map is also referred to as the symbol table. I mentioned earlier that it effects stability, but it's more in the way that it'll be harder to debug your system.

Here's the entries from the Makefile so you can see what's happening:

```
nm /boot/vmlinux-2.4.18-19.8.0 > System.map
# Below is the line from /usr/src/linux/Makefile 
nm vmlinux | grep -v '\(compiled\)\|\(\.o$$\)\|\( [aUw] \)\|\(\.\.ng$$\)\|\(LASH[RL]DI\)' | sort > System.map
cp /usr/src/linux/System.map /boot/System.map-2.4.18-14   # For v2.4.18
```

so first and foremost make sure that this copy is happening.

To complicate that a little more, if klogd isn't told where system.map is located it looks here:

1. /boot/System.map
2. /System.map
3. /usr/src/linux/System.map

It is possible that your Linux kernel compilation output to /usr/src/linux-version/System.map and klogd simply doesn't look there. A copy of the file will tell you right away if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have rebuilt the kernel several times, but this seems to keep happening (map file not including the 'version' line). I will try it again and watch closely for any errors. Do you know of any kernel configuration options that might affect the map file?

Comment: I'm going to revise my answer with some additional info...

Comment: thanks for your update. However, I am completely sure that the map file is being generated; is being copied to the correct location; and klogd is finding it. I have been copying the map file to the /boot directory myself, per the [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/kernel.html) instructions. I don't know if you saw my previous question, which I linked at the top, but the reason the map file is being rejected is because it doesn't contain the 'version' line that klogd is looking for.